# Initialize array with filename and unique parent directories, eliminating common directories

Tags: ruby, arrays

After initializing an array of file names from a base directory like so:

```
mydir = Dir[Dir.pwd + '/**/*.{txt,bat}']
```

I'm sorting the array in various ways such as:

```
mydir.sort_by! {|file| File.size(file)}.reverse!
```

The array names are comprised of files with a full pathname, with subdirectories ranging from 1 to 3 levels deep. Is there a way to initialize the array to eliminate the drive and common directories leaving only filenames (with extension) and their unique parent directories? In this case, I want to eliminate the following from every array name: C:\Downloads\My Files\ to achieve this. Note the space in "My Files".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what the common directory is, you can initialize the array with a code like this:

```
mydir = Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd) { Dir['**/*.{txt,bat}'] }
```

So with your example:

```
mydir = Dir.chdir('C:\Downloads\My Files') { Dir['**/*.{txt,bat}'] }
```

Note that `Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd) { Dir['**/*.{txt,bat}'] }` is equivalent to `Dir['**/*.{txt,bat}']`.

Comment: I got your code to work after removing the last backslash from the top directory like so: "C:\...\My Files". Works perfectly now. Useful info too. Thanks

Comment: I don't have Windows, couldn't really test the code. Glad you got it to work!

Comment: Yes, Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

The Pathname class has the `relative_path_from` method that might just fit your needs.

To use this class you need to require it:

```
require 'pathname'
```

You need to create instances of the Pathname class to use the method. You can do it like this:

```
mydir.map{|p| Pathname.new(p)}
```

You can then get the relative path from your current dir:

```
mydir.map{|p| Pathname.new(p).relative_path_from(Pathname.pwd)}
```

You said you just wanted the file names. To achieve this you can reject the directories:

```
mydir.map{|p| Pathname.new(p).relative_path_from(Pathname.pwd)}.reject(&:directory?)
```

Finally, you can sort by size the same way you did. Pathname does give you a shorter syntax though:

```
mydir.map{|p| Pathname.new(p).relative_path_from(Pathname.pwd)}.reject(&:directory?).sort_by(&:size).reverse
```

This will give you an array of Pathname objects, you can only get the strings with the `to_s` method:

```
mydir.map{|p| Pathname.new(p).relative_path_from(Pathname.pwd)}.reject(&:directory?).sort_by(&:size).reverse.map(&:to_s)
```

Also, as a size note, the `&:method` syntax is a shorthand for `{|x| x.method}`.

Comment: Works great. I evaluated this for last since it was more unfamiliar  than the other solutions and thus took more time to evaluate. Good to know information. Thanks

Comment: Although this is good to know information and related to the problem, only Gergo provided the solution that directly solved the issue of initializing an array in the manner requested. Thanks for posting this though. I gave it an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

The following method detects the common prefix from the strings in an array:

```
class Array
  def common_prefix
    first, *others = self
    i = 0
    loop{break unless first[i] and others.all?{|s| first[i] == s[i]}; i += 1}
    first[0, i]
  end
end
```

Using this, you can do

```
common_prefix = mydir.common_prefix
mydir_without_prefix = mydir.map{|s| s.sub(common_prefix, "")}
```

Comment: Nice. Indeed, this does work. Although it requires more code, I can see where this can be very useful. However, for this problem Gergo's quick and simple solution is difficult to beat. Will give this an up vote though because of it's potential.

Comment: I had in mind the case where all the matched files happen to share some more path than `Dir.pwd`. But this has shortcomings in that it may detect common prefix up to the middle of a directory/file name.

Comment: I didn't fully test this so I don't know how it would behave with subfolders of the same name, but at different levels and such. Need to be careful about that. Good work though. Addition -Your answer didn't show up when I made my response. I started thinking about those problems too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File::basename.

```
mydir = Dir[Dir.pwd + '/**/*.{txt,bat}']
mydir.sort_by! { |file| File.size(file) }.reverse!
files = mydir.map { |file| File.basename(file) }
```

Comment: I tried this and it only provides the base file name and no parent directories. Otherwise, the code works.

Comment: Ah! Misunderstood the question.